# Stepping down from being a NetEng Moderator

Tags: discussion

(nautical theme because why not? ;)

I was surprised when I was originally asked by the SE staff to be a moderator. Determined to be helpful, I set off with bravado and gusto to be a lightening rod to get our original "What's on Topic" written, and then went on to do my best to con this ship from the bridge. Now, the time has come for me to be relieved. Frankly, I'm weary of standing watch and am eager to be relieved of my powers. (They may already be gone by the time I press 'Post' :)

SE will soon (mid-June I believe) announce that we're having a moderator election to fill the vacated Moderator position. This is the perfect chance for a fresh face to step forward to serve the NetEng community.

Hopefully, this post will encourage some of you to consider throwing your hats into the ring when the election announcement appears. If you've not participated in an election, there is (or, at leaast, there has been previously) a chance for each candidate to state their platform/ideals. It's obviously beneficial to have several different platforms/ideals/plans for the community to choose from.

As others will tell you, there's a great sub-community of moderators (including the "Teacher's Lounge" chat room for moderators), and the SE staff has been responsive when I've had questions or needed assistance.

Meanwhile, I'm looking forward to chillaxing on the sun deck! ...and someone remind of the pool hours?!

Comment: Thanks for all you have done, but you will leave a hole. I hope you continue to participate.

Comment: I've said it in email already, but I want to publicly thank you on behalf of SE for the work you've done as a moderator for Network Engineering. To the rest of folks, your elections will begin on June 13th.

Comment: Craig, echoing GraceNote's comment... you were a huge part of launching the site and we greatly appreciate your efforts moderating the site.  Best luck with your future endeavors

Answer (score 7):

Craig, thank you for all the time and effort you put into making this SE what it is now.

SE staff confirmed that June 13th the elections will start.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for all your hard work, countless hours, and continued vigilance that have made this site a great resource.